# C++ lambda capture constraints

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Is it possible to constrain the type of capture of a lambda given as parameter ?
For example, Is it possible to take only lambdas that don't capture anything by reference ?

```
template <typename F>
void f(const F& lambda) // F must be a lambda that do not capture by ref
{
  :::
}
```

Comment: By the time the closure object hits your function, it has already been constructed, and you have no idea what's inside its guts, as those are private. But in case you were wondering, the lambda certainly can't capture anything *after the fact*, and in particular nothing from within *your* function `f`.

Comment: This would be pointless, since capturing a pointer by value is just as dangerous as capturing a reference.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is right.

Comment: @BenVoigt but in fact, technically you could have the full detail of captured variables with qualified types.

Comment: Here's an idea: If you have it, try throwing `is_trivially_copyable` at your class.

Comment: @Ugo: Is this just intellectual curiosity, or is there a particular problem you're trying to solve by doing such a thing? There might be a better approach.

Comment: @Hurkyl To be honest that's just curiosity. Lambda where advertised as bringing a functional taste to C++ and I am wondering how close we can get to pure FP. This would be relevant in a concurrent/parallel context ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSalters notes that "non-capturing lambda's can be converted to a pointer-to-function." What does this mean? The lambda object will match a pointer to function parameter type.

It's tricky to translate the lambda type to a pointer-to-function. Here is my attempt at a compliant implementation. It's slightly hackish.

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename fn >
struct ptmf_to_pf;

template< typename r, typename c, typename ... a >
struct ptmf_to_pf< r (c::*) ( a ... ) const >
    { typedef r (* type)( a ... ); };

// Use SFINAE to hide function if lambda is not convertible to function ptr.
// Only check that the conversion is legal, it never actually occurs.

template< typename lambda >
typename std::enable_if< std::is_constructible<
         typename ptmf_to_pf< decltype( &lambda::operator() ) >::type,
         lambda >::value >::type
f( lambda arg ) {
    arg( "hello " );
    arg( "world\n" );
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
int x = 3;
    f( []( char const *s ){ std::cout << s; } ); // OK
    f( [=]( char const *s ){ std::cout << s; } ); // OK
    f( [=]( char const *s ){ std::cout << s << x; } ); // error
}
```

This will not accept function pointers as direct arguments, since the template parameter needs to resolve to a functor. You could make it do so by providing a specialization for `ptmf_to_pf` that accepts pointer to function types.

Also, as the demo shows, it won't accept lambdas that capture anything by value, as well as by reference. There is no way in C++ to make the restriction so specific.

Comment: Why not just pass lambda as a function pointer then, without templates?

Comment: @perreal: If you know the desired function pointer type, then do so. In the general case this is not known.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you're misunderstanding the capturing behaviour of lambda expressions: A closure object is just like a functor object spelt out, so

```
struct Fun
{
    Fun (int & a) : n(a) { }
    int operator()(...) { ... }
private:
    int & n;
};

int q;
Fun f(q);
f(...);
```

is exactly the same as

```
int q;
auto f = [&q](...) -> int { ... };
f(...);
```

Once the closure object is constructed, all the capturing and binding is finished and forever locked into the object.

If you now pass the object on to some other place, like `call_me(f)`, then the recipient function has no connection with the construction of the functor or closure object.

Comment: That's true, but the lambda's compiler-generated type contains all the details of how the capture occurred.  One could easily imagine a metadata system that allowed introspection of that type to see whether there were any reference members (or whether the constructor has any reference parameters).

Answer (score 3):

Indirect hack: Only non-capturing lambda's can be converted to a pointer-to-function. Of course, that also covers a lot of `F` types that aren't lambda's at all.

Comment: Allowing non-lambda function pointers is probably harmless or beneficial. +1